# Передать данные из одного фрагмента в другой через Preferences

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Есть 2 фрагмента в одном активити которые сменяются слайдом(2 вкладки). 2 фрагмента: **ArmaturaWeight.java** и **ArmaturaLength.java**. Главное активити: **Armatura.java**. Необходимо передать данные поля ввода из одного фрагмента в другой.

---

**ArmaturaWeight.java**

Сохраняю данные поля ввода EditText в файл **uz.metallcenter.finalvmc_preferences.xml**

```
void saveText() {
      sPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
      Editor ed = sPref.edit();
      ed.putString(SAVED_TEXT, EditText1.getText().toString());
      ed.commit();
}
```

**ArmaturaLength.java**

Тут я пытаюсь загрузить эти данные. Но ничего не выходит. Подозреваю что тут .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext()); вместо getContext() нужно вставить что-то другое. Но вообще хз что.

```
void loadText() {
      ssPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
      String savedText = ssPref.getString(SAVED_TEXT2, "");
      EditText1.setText(savedText);
      Log.d("my_logs", savedText);
}
```

**Ошибка:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Этот же текст уже есть чуть выше. Я просто хотел наглядно показать где именно и какая ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Прошу прощения, была глупая ошибка

```
ssPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
String savedText = ssPref.getString(SAVED_TEXT2, "");
EditText1.setText(savedText);
Log.d("my_logs", savedText);
```

Вставил этот код в onCreateView под return view;
Из-за этого прога не компилилась

Comment: да, unreacheble statement - это недостижимый код, то есть код, который ни при каких условиях не будет выполнен (в вашем случае после оператора `return` в методе не может быть кода)